# Using log4j1.2-2 bridge, is it possible to dynamically configure the log settings

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

We are using the log4j1 to log4j2 bridge,

log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar

And our code uses the PropertyConfigu

```
System.getProperty( "appserver.Name" );
System.setProperty( "appserver.Name", "/usr/local/logs/server3" );
l4jprops.put( "appserver.Name", "/usr/local/logs/server3" );    

            
PropertyConfigurator.configure( l4jprops );
logger = Logger.getLogger(PfsSystemPropertiesServlet.class.getName());
```

Here is an example log4j setting.

```
log4j.appender.AuthAppender.File=${appserver.Name}/log4j_api_auth.log
log4j.appender.AuthAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

This currently doesnt seem to write the logs as we want, how can we get this code to work with the bridge.  That class available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until Log4j 2.17.1, `PropertyConfigurator` has been a no-op. That is going to change in the upcoming release (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-1.2-api/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.java)): your code should work **without any changes**.

In order to test the new release, add the [snapshots repository](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html#Snapshot_builds):

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>apache.snapshots</id>
    <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>https://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

and set the version of `log4j-1.2-api` to `2.17.2-SNAPSHOT`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit:** If you can't use snapshots or wait for the next release, the behavior of `PropertyConfigurator` can be emulated as follows:

```java
import org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration;

// PropertiesConfiguration only accepts an InputStream in 2.17.1
final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
l4jprops.save(os, null);
final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
// Initialize to prevent automatic configuration.
Configurator.initialize(new NullConfiguration());
final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
final Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(ctx, new ConfigurationSource(is), 0);
Configurator.reconfigure(config);
```

Comment: Lets say I cant use the snapshots.  Is there another way...just to get dynamic variables in the log4j property file.  Also point to a different path.

Comment: Thanks, do you work on log4j?

Comment: Can I also populate dynamic properties within a file that isnt the standard log4j.properties.  I will try.

Comment: What do you mean by _"standard `log4j.properties"_? The above snippet should work with any `Properties` containing Log4j related configuration. I don't work on Log4j, but we use Log4j 1.2 at work, so I've followed the recent changes.

Comment: One more question, is it possible to mix log4j2.xml and log4j.properties for same application

Comment: Yes, the `log4j2.configurationFile` property accepts a list of URLs, but you should probably post a separate question for it.

Comment: I tried this...didn't get the behavior I expected.

    try {
      final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/usr/local/pfs/conf/log4j_global.properties");
      l4jprops.load(fis); 
      l4jprops.put( "appserver.Name", "/usr/local/pfs/logs/server5/" );       
      
      Configurator.initialize(new NullConfiguration());
      final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
      final Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(ctx, new ConfigurationSource(fis), 0);
      Configurator.reconfigure(config);

Comment: Yea, that code above didn't seem to work, I couldn't change the path of the file dynamically.

This worked.

-Dlog4j1.compatibility=true
-Dlog4j.configuration=/usr/local/pfs/conf/log4j_global.properties

Comment: Did you check the log for errors? You can set `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` to see Log4j debug output on stderr.

Comment: Ok, it worked.  One more question, is there a way to pick up Appenders outside of the standard list in log4j.properties.  Say outside of the standard.  Say Socket Appender?

Comment: If you copy the appender code from Log4j 1.x and add it to your application, it might work (`log4j-1.2.-api` uses an adapter if it does not recognise the appender class). A safer way would be to write an [`AppenderBuilder`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/builders/appender/AppenderBuilder.html) that creates and configures a Log4j 2.x [`SocketAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/SocketAppender.html).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Does this mean that the 3 exceptions in the "Limitations of the Log4j 1.x bridge" section of https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html do not apply anymore?

Comment: The `log4j-1.2-api` will never have 100% binary compatibility with `log4j`. If you refer to classes other than `Logger`, `LogManager` in your code, your mileage might vary. As a rule of thumb: if your custom code does not work out-of-the-box with `log4j-1.2-api`, rewrite it using Log4j2 directly. If you think that the changes to `log4j-1.2-api` required are simple, you can also send a Github PR or open a JIRA issue.