# Loading log4j2.xml or properties configuration file during runtime by specifying path

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to load log4j2.xml or properties file from a specific location which will be provided at runtime.
This is part of a migration from log4j 1.x to log4j 2.x version. I have seen there are lots of changes in the logging configuration loading sequences in log4j2. So right now after searching I have the following methods below -

1 -

```
 Configurator.reconfigure(new URI("URI of your file"));
```

2 -

```
// import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
File file = new File("path/to/a/different/log4j2.xml");

// this will force a reconfiguration
context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
```

But they say that LoggerContext class is not part of the public API, is it still the case now ?

3-

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/path/to/log4j2.xml");
ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(inputStream);
Configurator.initialize(null, source);
```

4- Or simply

```
Configurator.initialize(null, "/path/to/log4j2.xml");
```

I am confused if all of these are viable or are to be used in different scenarios and have different outcomes.

Also the functions that I am trying to replace are DOMConfigurator and PropertyConfigurator. I know log4j2 will find configurations automatically in classpath but incase I have multiple configuration files for different environments etc or scenarios or the configuration file is outside the classpath, somewhere else on the system - I am trying to use these above functions to do it.
Please help as I am stuck here, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no `LoggerContext` is associated with the caller, all these methods have the same effect: they create a `LoggerContext` and configure it using the configuration source provided.

The 4 methods start to differ if there is a `LoggerContext` associated with the caller. This can happen if any `LogManager`'s `get*` method was called before (e.g. in a static initializer). If this happens, the first two methods will **replace** that context's configuration, while the last two are no-ops.

`PropertyConfigurator` and `DOMConfigurator` in Log4j 1.x worked differently: unless you used `log4j.reset=true` key they **modified** the previous configuration. Although the two classes have been ported to the newest `log4j-1.2-api`, the "reset" semantic is not implemented and they behave like `Configurator.reconfigure` restricted to a single configuration format.

**Remark**: `Configurator.reconfigure` tries to guess the configuration format to choose the appropriate `ConfigurationFactory`. Since both Log4j 2.x and Log4j 1.x have the properties and XML formats, all properties and XML files will interpreted as native Log4j2 configuration files. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70854599/11748454) for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solves the confusion to a large extent. So bottom line is if I have changed my log4j 1.x XML and properties files to the new log4j2.x format, I can load these configurations before the application starts using Configurator.initialize() right ?

Comment: _"Before the application starts"_ is hard to achieve, since usually even the main class has a static logger field. However, if the configuration file is called `log4j2.properties` (or `log4j2.xml` if you prefer a less messed-up format), Log4j 2 will pick it up automatically (see [automatic configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration)) and you don't need to do anything at all.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yep I am aware about the automatic loading of the log4j2.xml. Only problem here for me is that the log4j2.xml is not in classpath, its in the WEB-INF folder and not inside the classes folder under it. In this case I do need to load it via the path programatically right ?

Comment: I would still try a couple of alternatives before falling back to programmatic configuration: 1. the [Log4j2 system property](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties) `log4j2.configurationFile`, 2. a custom [ConfigurationFactory](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#ConfigurationFactory). And if programmatic configuration is needed I would rather use `Configurator.reconfigure`.

Comment: thank you again for following up, will try these alternate options and replace configure with reconfigure, as it seems like the safer one to use.

Comment: Is there anyway to mimic the behavior of the absence of the old log4j.reset=true parameter ? Because I have a situation now to modify the current configuration, and on the official log4j2 website I see they are using context.getConfiguration(); then use FileAppender.createAppender method to create the appender then add it to the existing configuration, but now its seems like the createAppender method is deprecated. Can I still use the .createAppender method, or are there any alternatives ?

Comment: I have figured it out no issue, thanks